# Execution time in C on Windows with i7, queryperformace/frequency and clock don't work

Tags: c, windows, query-performance, execution-time

I need to measure the time elapsed while my method is running. I have tried both `QueryPerformanceFrequency` with `QueryPerformanceCounter` as well as using `clock_t`(examples of both, which I got from similar questions on here):

```
LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
LARGE_INTEGER start;
LARGE_INTEGER end;
double interval;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
method(one, two, result);/***** Method I need timed *****/
QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
interval = (double) (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;
```

and for `clock_t` I have:

```
clock_t start, end;
start = clock();
method(one, two, result);/***** Method I need timed *****/
end = clock();
double timeElapsed = (double)(end-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

I have `#include <time.h>` for `clock_t` and `#include <windows.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` for the `QueryPerformanceFrequency` with `QueryPerformanceCounter`.
Every time I run this code with either method I get 0 as time elapsed. Is it possible that the code is running too fast to measure with the methods I am using above, and if so what is a way I can remedy this?